# Disable boot chime on late 2009 MacBook without macOS installed

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I would like to disable the boot/power-on chime on a late 2009 MacBook. However, my system does not have macOS installed at all. Is there a way to do this without reinstalling macOS?

The machine has Linux installed, though it often runs FreeBSD as well.

Comment: Are you able to boot into single-user mode holding ⌘S on boot?

Comment: No. Holding cmd+s on boot still boots me into my non-macOS operating system.

Comment: What OS doyou have installed?

Comment: The machine has Linux installed, though it often runs FreeBSD as well. I'd like a solution that is OS independent.

Comment: Just spitballing here but if you can access NVRAM in a shell there may be a command to do that, with a little research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Start up chime resides in the NVRAM.

To disable it in OS X  run `sudo nvram BootAudio=%00`

I found this for Linux:

```
# efivar -l | grep SystemAudioVolume
 7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82-SystemAudioVolume
 7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82-SystemAudioVolumeDB

# efivar -n 7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82-SystemAudioVolume -p
GUID: 7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82
Name: "SystemAudioVolume"
Attributes:
    Non-Volatile
    Boot Service Access
    Runtime Service Access
Value:
00000000  00                                                |.               |

# efivar -n 7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82-SystemAudioVolumeDB -p
GUID: 7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82
Name: "SystemAudioVolumeDB"
Attributes:
    Non-Volatile
    Boot Service Access
    Runtime Service Access
Value:
00000000  00 
#
```

[SOURCE](http://atodorov.org/blog/2015/04/27/disabling-macbook-startup-sound-in-linux/)